# angular 1.3.15 html5mode deeplinking, route, hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I enabled html5mode `true` and placed `<base href="/">` inside head tag. It seems to be working fine. But when I refresh a page, it gives me an error.

```
The requested URL /updated_1/work was not found on this server.
```

Found this in another post.

> This problem was due to the use of AngularJS 1.1.5 (which was unstable, and obviously had some bug or different implementation of the routing than it was in 1.0.7)
>
> turning it back to 1.0.7 solved the problem instantly.
>
> have tried the 1.2.0rc1 version, but have not finished testing as I had to rewrite some of the router functionality since they took it out of the core.
>
> anyway, this problem is fixed when using AngularJS vs 1.0.7.

Using old version gives more error. So I though to use latest version. I'm using  AngularJS v1.3.15.

Is that a problem with angular version? Can some one suggest with best solution.

Thanks

Comment: I have placed <base href="/"> inside head tag.

Comment: Please provide code snippet, which can help people to identify errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular.  If you don't do this, when the user refreshes, they get a blank screen.

Create an .htaccess file inside your folder, and paste in this ( assuming your main file is named index.html ).

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

If the problem still persist, let me know.