# Why does AngularJS ui-router only work within app?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, drupal-7, angular-ui-router

### Problem

ui-router works just fine within the app: when I click a relative link such as

```
<a href="browse/story/880">...</a>
```

it works as expected (yes, I know `ui-sref` is the correct way, but it's a long story and beside the point). As soon as I enter a full URL such as *http://localhost:3000/browse/story/880* into the address bar, however, I get **"Page not found"**.

### Environment

#### Pieces

- Vagrant/puppet
- Drupal 7-something
- Nginx
- AngularJS 1.3.4
- ui-router 0.2.14

#### Routes

```
angular.module('mapApp')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        /* Set base */
        $('head').append('<base href="/"/>');

        /* Enable HTML5 mode */
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        /* Configure routes */
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/browse',
            template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        })
        .state('home.story', {
            url: '/story/:interview_number',
            template: '<div></div>',
            controller: 'PopupCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                /* ... stuff ... */
            },
        });
    }
]);
```

#### Nginx

If it matters, this is in */etc/nginx/sites-available/h48blbvrwu5z1.conf*:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           1947partitionarchive.dev ;
  client_max_body_size 1m;

  root /var/www/drupal;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/h48blbvrwu5z1.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/h48blbvrwu5z1.error.log;

  location / {
    root  /var/www/drupal;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {  
    root  /var/www/drupal;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;    
  }
  sendfile off;
}
```

### Referenced Resources

- [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) on ui-router's Github FAQ
- [Some gists](https://gist.github.com/zdwolfe/6721115)
- Every related S.O. question I could find

### Other Observations

Not sure if these help troubleshooting, but here you go:

- Did not have this problem when I was NOT using HTML5 mode
- Also prior to HTML5 mode, my URLs looked like *http://localhost:3000/browse#/story/880* rather than with the typical slash before the # sign like you normally see with ui-router: *http://localhost:3000/browse/#/story/880*
- My "Page not found" attempts do not appear in the Nginx error log
- Server stuff is hard

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you allowed direct-linking by any chance?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's an Nginx thing I presume? If it's not something in my config file above then no I haven't.

Comment: Hm, see my answer here in another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252150/angular-1-3-15-html5mode-deeplinking-route-hash/30297740#30297740   - If this doesn't work, i'll try to investigate deeper